# Install/test problem with full Nativescript CLI install

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, nativescript, tns

I've done an apparently clean install of the Nativescript CLI on MacOS X, yet when I run tns doctor it fails:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns doctor

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/verify-node-    version.js:32
            console.warn((`${os.EOL}${nodeWarning.message}${os.EOL}`).yellow.bold)
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns:8:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Node.js version that is not supported. What is the output of `node --version`?

Comment: bash-3.2$ node --version
v0.10.29

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using very old Node.js version. NativeScript CLI requires at least Node.js 6, but I recommend you to use current LTS - Node.js 10.
Node.js 0.10.29 (which is your current version) does not support the syntax used in NativeScript CLI's codebase.

Comment: You are right except the latest CLI (5.x) requires at least Node 8.

Comment: Thank you - the node update/upgrade process on macOS X Mojave gave me v0.10.29; installing Node8 moved me further along. Now the problem is:
bash-3.2$ sudo tns doctor
Password:********
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
...

Comment: I assume this is a path problem, but moving a link to the modules directory all over doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The former problem was due to an obsolete version of node,js; installation of node 10 (LTS) solved it.

The latter problem was due to a writhing nest of pythons - the command 'python' linked to python 2.5, while the install script invoked python 2.7 and its attendant user addons. Relinking 'python' to the python 2.7 executable fixed the issue.